# How to create product slider in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to create a product slider in bootstrap like the one in image below that shows the big image on left with details on the right above the thumbnail slider.

I want one modification to the following image. I want to have thumbnail slider below the big image that shows the other images of same product but the thumbnail slider on the right should navigate to the next product.

[image: Product slider]

**my html codes**

```
<div class="pull"></div>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class ="row">
    <li id="product">
    <div class="pad"> 
        <div class ="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="col1">
                  <div class="gallery_big_img">
                    <img src="images/doubleRound/all parts.JPG" alt="" class="img1" id="active">
                    <img src="images/doubleRound/bottom.JPG" alt="" class="img2">
                    <img src="images/doubleRound/front_side.JPG" alt="" class="img3">
                    <img src="images/doubleRound/front.JPG" alt="" class="img4">
                    <img src="images/doubleRound/top.JPG" alt="" class="img5">
                    <img src="images/singleRound/all parts.JPG" alt="" class="img6">
                    <img src="images/singleRound/down.JPG" alt="" class="img7">
                    <img src="images/singleRound/front.JPG" alt="" class="img8">
                    <img src="images/singleRound/front_side.JPG" alt="" class="img9">
                    <img src="images/singleRound/top_back.JPG" alt="" class="img10">
                  </div>
                </div>
        <div class ="col-md-12 col-md-6">
          <div class="col1 pad_left1">
                  <h2>Products</h2>
                  <div id="caption">
                    <ul>
                      <li class="img1">
                        <p class="pad_bot1"><strong>Double Shape All Parts</strong><br>
                            Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum tet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata.</p>
                        <p>Danctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit tempor invidunt ut labore.</p>
                      </li>
                      <li class="img2">
                        <p class="pad_bot1"><strong>Double Round Bottom</strong><br>
                            Sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum tet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata.</p>
                        <p>Est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit tempor invidunt ut labore.</p>
                      </li>
                      <li class="img3">
                        <p class="pad_bot1"><strong>Double Round Front Side</strong><br>
                            Elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum tet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata.</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit tempor invidunt ut labore.</p>
                      </li>
                      <li class="img4">
                        <p class="pad_bot1"><strong>Double Round Front</strong><br>
                            Sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum tet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata.</p>
                        <p>Ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit tempor invidunt ut labore.</p>
                      </li>
                      <li class="img5">
                        <p class="pad_bot1"><strong>Double Round Top</strong><br>
                            Diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum tet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata.</p>
                        <p>Dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit tempor invidunt ut labore.</p>
                      </li>
                      <li class="img6">
                        <p class="pad_bot1"><strong>Signle Round All Parts</strong><br>
                            Diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum tet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata.</p>
                        <p>Dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit tempor invidunt ut labore.</p>
                      </li>
                      <li class="img7">
                        <p class="pad_bot1"><strong>Signle Round Down</strong><br>
                            Diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum tet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata.</p>
                        <p>Dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit tempor invidunt ut labore.</p>
                      </li>
                      <li class="img8">
                        <p class="pad_bot1"><strong>Signle Round Front</strong><br>
                            Diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum tet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata.</p>
                        <p>Dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit tempor invidunt ut labore.</p>
                      </li>
                      <li class="img9">
                        <p class="pad_bot1"><strong>Signle Round Front Side</strong><br>
                            Diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum tet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata.</p>
                        <p>Dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit tempor invidunt ut labore.</p>
                      </li>
                      <li class="img10">
                        <p class="pad_bot1"><strong>Signle Round Top Back</strong><br>
                            Diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum tet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata.</p>
                        <p>Dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit tempor invidunt ut labore.</p>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="relative">
                    <div id="gallery1" class="small_img">
                      <ul>
                      <li><a href="#img1"><img src="images/doubleRound/all parts.JPG" alt=""></a></li>
                      <li><a href="#img2"><img src="images/doubleRound/bottom.JPG" alt=""></a></li>
                      <li><a href="#img3"><img src="images/doubleRound/front_side.JPG" alt=""></a></li>
                      <li><a href="#img4"><img src="images/doubleRound/front.JPG" alt=""></a></li>
                      <li><a href="#img5"><img src="images/doubleRound/top.JPG" alt=""></a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#img6"><img src="images/singleRound/all parts.JPG" alt=""></a></li>
                      <li><a href="#img7"><img src="images/singleRound/down.JPG" alt=""></a></li>
                      <li><a href="#img8"><img src="images/singleRound/front.JPG" alt=""></a></li>
                      <li><a href="#img9"><img src="images/singleRound/front_side.JPG" alt=""></a></li>
                      <li><a href="#img10"><img src="images/singleRound/top_back.JPG" alt=""></a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="prev"><span></span></a>
                    <a href="#" class="next"><span></span></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
        </div>

        </div>
        </li>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

but above code is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually super simple to do in Bootstrap without any extra plugins or even a single line of javascript.

### Here's a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/NxeZ3/)**

Here's a basic layout that roughly matches your design. Style it up how you want.  This takes advantage of the Bootstrap data-target and data-slide-to options.  The data-target is the id of your carousel and the data-slide-to is just a number representing the slide (which is 0 based, so slide 1 is set to data-slide-to="0").

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/e8117f/fff&text=Product+Main">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/00ffff/000&text=Product+Image+2">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/ff00ff/fff&text=Product+Image+3">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/ffff00/000&text=Product+Image+4">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix">
              <div class="carousel-link">
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="thumb"><img src="http://placehold.it/100/e8117f/fff&text=Product+Main"></div>
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1" class="thumb"><img src="http://placehold.it/100/00ffff/000&text=Product+Image+2"></div>
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2" class="thumb"><img src="http://placehold.it/100/ff00ff/fff&text=Product+Image+3"></div>
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="3" class="thumb"><img src="http://placehold.it/100/ffff00/000&text=Product+Image+4"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div> <!-- /col-sm-6 -->
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h2>Products</h2>
        <h3>Some product subhead</h3>
        <p>Product description goes here.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
        <p>Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.</p>
    </div> <!-- /col-sm-6 -->
  </div> <!-- /row -->
</div> <!-- /container -->
```

and here's some extra styles for the thumbnail images that are used to switch the carousel.

```
.carousel-link .thumb {
    width: 25%;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
}
.carousel-link .thumb img {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2px;
}
.carousel-link .thumb:first-of-type img {
    padding-left: 0;
}
.carousel-link .thumb:last-of-type img {
    padding-right: 0;
}
.item img {
    width: 100%;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow, pretty cool. All the above answers are awesome. I actually needed a content slider for Bootstrap 5 my project. So, here's what I came up with.

Basically, I used jQuery and Light slider to get my job done.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightslider/1.1.6/css/lightslider.min.css" />
        <title>Hello, world!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="main-header mt-5">
                    <h1 class="fs-4">Content Slider for Bootstrap 5</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-4">
            <ul id="card-slider">
                <li>
                    <div class="card">
                        <img src="https://placehold.co/600x300" alt="Card Title">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h3 class="fs-6">Card Title</h3>
                            <p class="small">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="card">
                        <img src="https://placehold.co/600x300" alt="Card Title">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h3 class="fs-6">Card Title</h3>
                            <p class="small">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="card">
                        <img src="https://placehold.co/600x300" alt="Card Title">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h3 class="fs-6">Card Title</h3>
                            <p class="small">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="card">
                        <img src="https://placehold.co/600x300" alt="Card Title">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h3 class="fs-6">Card Title</h3>
                            <p class="small">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="card">
                        <img src="https://placehold.co/600x300" alt="Card Title">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h3 class="fs-6">Card Title</h3>
                            <p class="small">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="card">
                        <img src="https://placehold.co/600x300" alt="Card Title">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h3 class="fs-6">Card Title</h3>
                            <p class="small">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightslider/1.1.6/js/lightslider.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#card-slider').lightSlider();
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```